# Fail in building and packaging logback-android

Tags: maven, repository, logback

I am a new to maven world, and i just want to try and use the logback-android jar.
But i can not download the v1.0.8-1 from the internet.
Then I try to compile and package it from git.
I do what it says on the project's home page in github (github.com/tony19/logback-android).

1.git clone ...-> ok;

2.mvn -P debug clean install -> but it says there are errors during testing and build failed.

---

Then i try to skip the testing phase.

mvn -P debug clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

At this time, it would say

*"
     Path to denpendency:
     1) com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:jar:1.0.11-1-SNAPSHOT
     2) com..github.tony19:logback-android-core:test-ja:testsr:1.0.11-1-SNAPSHOT
     ----------
     1 required artifact is missing.
     for artifact:
        com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:jar:1.0.11-1-SNAPSHOT
     from the specitied remote repositories:
      central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
      sonatype-nexus-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots)
"*

It really installes the logback-android-core.jar in the local maven repository. But why the next step, building classic module would like to get the core module from the oss.sonatype.org net insteading of the local repository????

---

My Runing Environment:
Git Bash(git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1)
Apach Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-07 03:16:01+0800)
java version: 1.7.0_11
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: GBK
OS name: "windows xp" version: "5.1" arch: "x86" Family: "windows"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `logback-android-classic` depends on a [`test-jar`](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/blob/10b1d0bd6f49aa1a3405ce320cf818f2af2bc876/logback-classic/pom.xml#L45), which has a [known problem](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAR-138) in that the `test-jar` dependencies are still required even when tests are skipped with `maven.test.skip`.

The workaround is to use `skipTests` instead:

```
$ mvn -P debug clean install -DskipTests=true
```

Note the difference is that `skipTests` still builds the test source (creating the required `test-jar`) but does not run the tests, while `maven.test.skip` skips both.

However, from a recent [commit](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/commit/10b1d0bd6f49aa1a3405ce320cf818f2af2bc876) in `logback-android`, it looks like you can just run [`makejar.sh`](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/blob/10b1d0bd6f49aa1a3405ce320cf818f2af2bc876/makejar.sh) from the root of the source directory.